# Templates being ignored when multiple Elsticsearch outputs are used in the same Logstash config file

Tags: json, templates, elasticsearch, logstash, mappings

I wrote a Logstash config file with three file inputs (all of them are log files), three filters (each of them with a different pattern) and three elasticsearch outputs (each of them goes to a different index). Each index has a different template according to their input type and indexes are partitioned by weeks.

The issue happend when the described config file runs, the index templates are ignored and don't take effect on indexes creation.

Templates don't work in this case:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/path/to/file.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
        type => 'type_1'
        }
    file {
        path => "/path/to/file2.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
        type => 'type_2'
    }
    file {
        path => ["/path/to/file3.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
        type => 'type_3'
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "type_1" {
        csv {
            columns => ["column1","column2","column3"]
                separator => "|"
        }
        date {
            match => [ "column3", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
        date {
            match => [ "column3", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
            target => "column3"
        }   
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
            remove_field => [ "path" ]
            remove_field => [ "host" ]
        }
    }
    if [type] == "type_2" {
        csv {
            columns => ["column1","column2",]
            separator => "|"
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
            remove_field => [ "path" ]
            remove_field => [ "host" ]
            convert => { "column1" => "float" }
        }
        date {
            match => [ "column2", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
        date {
            match => [ "column2", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
            target => "column2"
        }
    }
    if [type] == "type_3" {
        csv {
            columns => ["column1","column2","column3","column4"]
            separator => "|"
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
            remove_field => [ "path" ]
            remove_field => [ "host" ]
            convert => { "column3" => "float" }
            convert => { "column1" => "float" }
        }
        date {
            match => [ "column4", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
        date {
             match => [ "column4", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
             target => "column4"
        }
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "type_1" {
        elasticsearch { 
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "type_1-%{+xxxx.ww}"
        }
    }
    if [type] == "type_2" {
        elasticsearch { 
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "type_2-%{+xxxx.ww}"
        }
    }
    if [type] == "type_3" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "type_3-%{+xxxx.ww}"
        }
    }
}
```

Opposite, templates works fine when a single config file is used for each  input file type, filters and elasticsearch outputs.

Templates works fine here:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/path/to/file.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
        }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["column1","column2","column3"]
            separator => "|"
    }
    date {
        match => [ "column3", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
    date {
        match => [ "column3", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" ]
        target => "column3"
    }   
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "message" ]
        remove_field => [ "path" ]
        remove_field => [ "host" ]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "type_1-%{+xxxx.ww}"
    }
}
```

I've already used the following parameters in the config file:

- template => "file_name.json"
- template_overwrite => "true"
- manage_template => "true"
- template_name => "template_name"

But they didn't help.

Has anyone had this error before?

(I'm working with elasticsearch 2.3.2 and logstash 2.3.2)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

---

My templates

type_1

```
 curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/_template/type_1' -d '
    {
      "template": "type_1*", 
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "refresh_interval" : "30s"
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "logs" : {
            "_all": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "_source": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties" : {
                 "column3" : {
                    "type" : "date",
                    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                  },
                  "@timestamp" : {
                    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                    "type" : "date",
                                "norms": {
                                    "enabled": false
                                }
                  },
                  "column2" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"             
                  },
                  "column1" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "@version" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                  }
             }
         }
      }
    }';
```

type_2

```
 curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/_template/type_2' -d '
    {
      "template": "type_2*", 
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "refresh_interval" : "30s"
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "logs" : {
            "_all": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "_source": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties" : {
                 "column2" : {
                    "type" : "date",
                    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                  },
                  "@timestamp" : {
                    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                    "type" : "date",
                                "norms": {
                                    "enabled": false
                                }
                  },
                  "column1" : {
                    "type" : "float",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"             
                  },
                  "@version" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                  }
             }
         }
      }
    }';
```

type_3

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/_template/type_3' -d '
{
  "template": "type_3*", 
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "refresh_interval" : "30s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "logs" : {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_source": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties" : {
             "column4" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                    "norms": {
                        "enabled": false
                    }
              },
              "@timestamp" : {
                "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                "type" : "date",
                            "norms": {
                                "enabled": false
                            }
              },
              "column3" : {
                "type" : "float",
                "index": "not_analyzed"             
              },
              "column2" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"             
              },
               "column1" : {
                "type" : "float",
                "index": "not_analyzed"             
              },
              "@version" : {
                "type" : "string",
                    "norms": {
                        "enabled": false
                    }
              }
         }
     }
  }
}';
```

Comment: Your config doesn't specify the template, so you've installed it in ES?  If so, how, and you please include it in your question.

Comment: I have tried this options; Installing templates using curl on Elasticsearch  and using template_name => "template_name" on config file, also specifying the json file using template => "file_name.json" and template_overwrite => "true" on config file to load and override Templates from json file. Templates are shown properly on ES when I query them.

Comment: If you install them in ES, you don't need to try to manage them with LS.  Thanks for including the templates in your question.  Are you working with indexes that were created *after* the templates were applied?

Comment: Yes, indexes are created after templates, actually indexes are created when logstash load data from logs and acording to creation date field data are mapped to one index or other. We use partitioned indexes by weeks

Comment: Just to be clear...  When an index is created, the mapping for fields added then is fixed.  Applying a template *after* the index is created won't affect the mapping.

Comment: Affirmative ...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

Losgstash config file uses type => 'type_1' to diferenciate between input files, filteres and Elasticsearch outputs, but also defines a template type and a new  field named "type".

We was using default type in Mapping templates "logs" and we wasn't cosdifering the 'type_1' defined in logstash config file. By this reason Templates was ignored.

The solution: Changing type in templates's mappings the issue is resolved.

For example:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/_template/type_1' -d '
    {
      "template": "type_1*", 
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "refresh_interval" : "30s"
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "type_1" : {
            "_all": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "_source": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties" : {
                 "column3" : {
                    "type" : "date",
                    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                  },
                  "@timestamp" : {
                    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                    "type" : "date",
                                "norms": {
                                    "enabled": false
                                }
                  },
                  "column2" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"             
                  },
                  "column1" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "@version" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                  }
             }
         }
      }
    }';
```